# Form Post Data Error

Tags: php, html

I have created a short form which is supposed to take data from three text areas, and combine them. It seems that the output of my data is "0". Any ideas why this much be so? Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<?php
function get_text() {
    $text = trim($_POST['one']);
    $textAr = explode("\n", $text);
    $textAr = array_filter($textAr, 'trim');

    $text2 = trim($_POST['two']);
    $textAr2 = explode("\n", $text2);
    $textAr2 = array_filter($textAr2, 'trim');

    $text3 = trim($_POST['three']);
    $textAr3 = explode("\n", $text3);
    $textAr3 = array_filter($textAr3, 'trim');

    return array($textAr, $textAr2, $textAr3);
}
?>

<form name="merge" method="POST">
    <textarea name="one" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
    <textarea name="two" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
    <textarea name="three" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
    <br /><input type="submit" name="done" value="Merge" /><br /><br />
    <textarea name="result" rows="10" cols="60">
    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['done'])) {
        list($textAr, $textAr2, $textAr3) = get_text();
        for ($i=0; $i < count($textAr); $i++)
            for ($j=0; $j < count($textAr2); $j++)
                for ($k=0; $k < count($textAr3); $k++)
                    echo($textAr[$i] + $textAr2[$j] + $textAr3[$k]);
    }
    ?></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `.` (dot) to concat a strings in php try change

```
echo($textAr[$i] + $textAr2[$j] + $textAr3[$k]);
```

to

```
echo $textAr[$i].$textAr2[$j].$textAr3[$k];
```

Comment: That actually works! Now my problem is that the words are merged together, but they go to the next line. For instance, if i had "apple" in the first textarea, and "orange" in the second textarea, the output would be, separated by a line: 
apple
orange.How do i make it such that its apple orange?

Answer (score 0):

Your output is correct as i have tried your code in my local xamp server and it is working perfectly it merges the three values correctly. you can check out the screenshot below

[image]

The problem might be with your server , restarting might help you. Or try it with new browser other than the one you are using.